# How to eliminate polarization mismatch in the Michelson interferometer based on single-mode optical fiber?

Tags: optics, interference, polarization, fiber-optics, waveguide

We are developing a mobile system for optical coherence tomography based on fiber optic Michelson interferometer. We are facing a problem of chenging the polarization during a movement of the fiber. As I understand we need to plug two polarization controllers in base arm and in measurement arm. Is it a best idea? And where can I read more?

And the second question is how to choose a proper type of polarization controller? I can't understand we need to use a two or three paddles (loops) polarization controllers. As I understand it depands on input type and output type of polarization.

Comment: You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization-maintaining_optical_fiber#:~:text=In%20fiber%20optics%2C%20polarization%2Dmaintaining,is%20little%20or%20no%20cross%2D